# How do I export text from a table and Shapes in PPT to CSV/ Excel file using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have code to export text from textbox in a PPT to CSV.

PFB the Link

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00950_Export_the_text_of_a_presentation_to_a_CSV-Excel_file.htm

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more informations before anyone will be able to really help you. For starters you should mention what you have tried (including your current code), and try to describe where exactly you're currently stuck. Maybe consider having a look at the following link: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bear in mind that the code example there is quite old, probably written originally for PPT '97, the first version that had VBA. Later versions have added features like tables, smartart and the like that would require special-case handling in order to extract the text.